# How to create distinct set from other sets?

Tags: algorithm, set, distinct, combinatorics

While solving the problems on Techgig.com, I got struck with one one of the problem. The problem is like this:

> A company organizes two trips for their employees in a year. They want
>   to know whether all the employees can be sent on the trip or not. The
>   condition is like, no employee can go on both the trips. Also to
>   determine which employee can go together the constraint is that the
>   employees who have worked together in past won't be in the same group.
>   Examples of the problems:
>
> Suppose the work history is given as follows: {(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)};
>   then it is possible to accommodate all the four employees in two trips
>   (one trip consisting of employees 1& 3 and other having employees 2 &
>   4). Neither of the two employees in the same trip have worked together
>   in past. Suppose the work history is given as {(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)} then
>   there is no way possible to have two trips satisfying the company rule
>   and accommodating all the employees.

Can anyone tell me how to proceed on this problem?

I am using this code for DFS and coloring the vertices.

```
static boolean DFS(int rootNode) {
        Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
        s.push(rootNode);
        state[rootNode] = true;
        color[rootNode] = 1;
        while (!s.isEmpty()) {
            int u = s.peek();
            for (int child = 0; child < numofemployees; child++) {
                if (adjmatrix[u][child] == 1) {
                    if (!state[child]) {
                        state[child] = true;
                        s.push(child);
                        color[child] = color[u] == 1 ? 2 : 1;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        s.pop();
                        if (color[u] == color[child])
                            return false;
                    }    

                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This problem is functionally equivalent to testing if an undirected graph is [bipartite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph).  A bipartite graph is a graph for which all of the nodes can be distributed among two sets, and within each set, no node is adjacent to another node.

To solve the problem, take the following steps.

1. Using the adjacency pairs, construct an undirected graph.  This is pretty straightforward: each number represents a node, and for each pair you are given, form a connection between those nodes.
2. Test the newly generated graph for bipartiteness.  This can be achieved in linear time, [as described here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph#Testing_bipartiteness).
3. If the graph is bipartite and you've generated the two node sets, the answer to the problem is yes, and each node set, along with its nodes (employees), correspond to one of the two trips.

Excerpt on how to test for bipartiteness:

> It is possible to test whether a graph is bipartite, and to return
>   either a two-coloring (if it is bipartite) or an odd cycle (if it is
>   not) in linear time, using depth-first search. The main idea is to
>   assign to each vertex the color that differs from the color of its
>   parent in the depth-first search tree, assigning colors in a preorder
>   traversal of the depth-first-search tree. This will necessarily
>   provide a two-coloring of the spanning tree consisting of the edges
>   connecting vertices to their parents, but it may not properly color
>   some of the non-tree edges. In a depth-first search tree, one of the
>   two endpoints of every non-tree edge is an ancestor of the other
>   endpoint, and when the depth first search discovers an edge of this
>   type it should check that these two vertices have different colors. If
>   they do not, then the path in the tree from ancestor to descendant,
>   together with the miscolored edge, form an odd cycle, which is
>   returned from the algorithm together with the result that the graph is
>   not bipartite. However, if the algorithm terminates without detecting
>   an odd cycle of this type, then every edge must be properly colored,
>   and the algorithm returns the coloring together with the result that
>   the graph is bipartite.

Comment: One note: it is possible to effectively "merge" steps 1 and 2 by walking through the provided "employee adjacency set" and constructing your disjoint sets that way.  This approach would be a bit more direct, but I thought the answer I provided above would be more illustrative.

Comment: I have used DFS to traverse the graph and colored the vertices but I am not passing all the test cases. I am not sure where I am going wrong. I have posted the code I am using above.

Answer (score 0):

I even used a recursive solution but this one is also passing the same number of cases. Am I leaving any special case handling ?

Below is the recursive solution of the problem:

```
static void dfs(int v, int curr) {
        state[v] = true;
        color[v] = curr;

        for (int i = 0; i < numofemployees; i++) {
            if (adjmatrix[v][i] == 1) {
                if (color[i] == curr) {
                    bipartite = false;
                    return;
                }

                if (!state[i])
                    dfs(i, curr == 1 ? 2 : 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am calling this function from `main()` as `dfs(0,1)` where `0` is the starting vertex and `1` is one of the color

Comment: The code you posted doesn't define a number of variables.  Could you post the rest?

Comment: @cheeken I am using a boolean array `state[numofemployees]` which have been initialized to false and another integer array `color[numofemployees]` initialized to 0. And `adjmatrix[numofemployees][numofemployees]` in a 2-D integer array (adjacency matrix). These all variables are class members and not local variables.